# Applescript to save a webpage to apple notes?

Tags: applescript, notes.app

I'm fairly new to Applescript. I would like to develop an Applescript that saves a webpage to Apple notes, instead of doing it manually by going to the 'Share' icon on the upper right of Safari and selecting Notes. Currently I have this script, but it only saves the webpage name and the url, unlike the method from above which saves a nice snapshot (by some unknown reason this script also messes up the notes formatting, making all the note contents to look tiny).

```
tell application "Safari"
    set myname to name of document 1
    set myurl to URL of document 1
end tell

tell application "Notes"
    set body of note "inbox" to (get body of note "inbox" & myname & " " & myurl)
end tell
```

Comment: How would you trigger such a script?

Comment: I’m thinking of triggering it via a workflow in Alfred.

Comment: Generally speaking the folks here at AD are happy to help with Applescripting, helping you troubleshoot your scripts, etc. But you will need to add what you have already come up with to your question so that the folks conversant with AppleScript can assist.